# How can I set the color/material of an object added/appended from another file?

Tags: python, materials, scripting, color, blend-files

It is not possible to set the color of the object added from the file. What am I doing wrong?

```
import bpy
import os
from pathlib import Path


file_path = 'd:/BlendetSkin002/280154.blend'      
inner_path = 'Object'           
object_name = 'scirt01'         


def append_scirt( path: Path):
    bpy.ops.wm.append(
            filepath=os.path.join(file_path, inner_path, object_name),
            directory=os.path.join(file_path, inner_path),
            filename=object_name,
            active_collection = True
            )
    rgba_color = (220, 0, 220, 0.99)
    material = bpy.data.materials.new(f"scirt01")
    material.diffuse_color = rgba_color
    bpy.context.active_object.data.materials.append(material)
    bpy.context.object.active_material.diffuse_color = rgba_color


append_scirt( Path(f'd:/BlendetSkin002/280154.blend'))
```

Comment: Do you want to replace the material of the appended object or just change the color in its material (this would mean you need some assumptions about the imported material)? In any case, `diffuse_color` is only for the viewport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you append an object from another file it is not fully selected, as seen in the orange outline. It has to have yellow outline to be active. That's why `bpy.context.object` and `bpy.context.active_object` return nothing. After appending just add the line `bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.context.scene.objects.get(object_name)` to make it the active object.

```
import bpy
import os
from pathlib import Path

file_path = 'd:/BlendetSkin002/280154.blend'      
inner_path = 'Object'           
object_name = 'scirt01'         

def append_scirt( path: Path):
    bpy.ops.wm.append(
            filepath=os.path.join(file_path, inner_path, object_name),
            directory=os.path.join(file_path, inner_path),
            filename=object_name,
            active_collection = True
            )
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.context.scene.objects.get(object_name)
    rgba_color = (220, 0, 220, 0.99)
    material = bpy.data.materials.new(f"scirt01")
    material.diffuse_color = rgba_color
    bpy.context.active_object.data.materials.append(material)
    bpy.context.object.active_material.diffuse_color = rgba_color

append_scirt(Path(file_path))
```